# How can I get IEdmEntityTypeReference.Key() to return keys in the correct order?

Tags: c#, odata

I'm working with OData, something I'm not too familiar with. When OData attaches an entity to the Context in the [DataServiceContext](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/blob/master/src/Microsoft.OData.Client/DataServiceContext.cs) class, they set the `.Identity` property using ODataResourceMetadataBuilder.

```
ODataResourceMetadataBuilder entityMetadataBuilder = this.GetEntityMetadataBuilderInternal(descriptor);

descriptor.EditLink = entityMetadataBuilder.GetEditLink();
descriptor.Identity = entityMetadataBuilder.GetId();
```

This goes through a series of OData classes starting with [ConventionalODataEntityMetadataBuilder.GetId()](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/blob/master/src/Microsoft.OData.Client/ConventionalODataEntityMetadataBuilder.cs), that eventually gets to where the CompositeKey is created in OData's [DataServiceUrlKeyDelimiter](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/blob/master/src/Microsoft.OData.Client/DataServiceUrlKeyDelimiter.cs)

```
internal void AppendKeyExpression(IEdmStructuredValue entity, StringBuilder builder)
{
    Debug.Assert(entity != null, "entity != null");
    Debug.Assert(builder != null, "builder != null");

    IEdmEntityTypeReference edmEntityTypeReference = entity.Type as IEdmEntityTypeReference;
    if (edmEntityTypeReference == null || !edmEntityTypeReference.Key().Any())
    {
        throw Error.Argument(ErrorStrings.Content_EntityWithoutKey, "entity");
    }

    // Problem occurs here - edmEntityTypeReference.Key() has the keys in the wrong order.
    this.AppendKeyExpression(edmEntityTypeReference.Key().ToList(), p => p.Name, p => GetPropertyValue(entity.FindPropertyValue(p.Name), entity.Type), builder);
}
```

The keys are defined in my class using Key Annotations

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid CompositeKeyB { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid CompositeKeyA { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the keys are alphabetically backwards.

When the above code runs to set the `.Identity` field, it is giving me the keys in alphabetical order, not in the order I specified in the Data Annotations.

This is a problem because when an entity is retrieved, the Keys are in the correct order so it has a different `.Identity` property and is seen as a separate instance than the attached instance. This means that it doesn't update the Attached entity with the new data, and also that a second copy of the entity gets created in the Context.

Is there an easy way to correct this, or am I stuck with writing my own code to get the Keys in the correct order using Reflection? I do not currently see a way of finding the Order value in the `IEdmStructuralProperty` property that is returned from `IEdmEntityTypeReference.Key()`.

Comment: Seems to me like a bug in Microsoft.OData.Client library. Maybe you could report the issue here https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues?

Comment: Thanks, I believe a coworker is going to report the bug. I'll post our solution that we found here though in case anyone else comes across the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was occurring because in the `ClientEdmModel.GetOrCreateEdmTypeInternal` method it is ordering the properties by name before sorting them into key and non-key properties.

```
// Problem is the .OrderBy in this line of code
foreach (PropertyInfo property in ClientTypeUtil.GetPropertiesOnType(type, /*declaredOnly*/edmBaseType != null).OrderBy(p => p.Name))
{
    IEdmProperty edmProperty = this.CreateEdmProperty((EdmStructuredType)entityType, property);
    loadedProperties.Add(edmProperty);

    if (edmBaseType == null && keyProperties.Any(k => k.DeclaringType == type && k.Name == property.Name))
    {
        Debug.Assert(edmProperty.PropertyKind == EdmPropertyKind.Structural, "edmProperty.PropertyKind == EdmPropertyKind.Structural");
        Debug.Assert(edmProperty.Type.TypeKind() == EdmTypeKind.Primitive || edmProperty.Type.TypeKind() == EdmTypeKind.Enum, "edmProperty.Type.TypeKind() == EdmTypeKind.Primitive || edmProperty.Type.TypeKind() == EdmTypeKind.Enum");
        loadedKeyProperties.Add((IEdmStructuralProperty)edmProperty);
    }
}
```

The solution we used was to apply the original sorting to composite key properties afterwards, although a potential solution could also be to remove the `.OrderBy(p => p.Name)` from the foreach loop. I'm not sure if this would cause other problems though, so it seems safest to just re-apply the key sort order afterwards for composite keys.

```
if (loadedKeyProperties.Count > 1)
{
    var orderedKeyPropertyNames = keyProperties.Select(k => k.Name).ToList();
    loadedKeyProperties = loadedKeyProperties.OrderBy(k => orderedKeyPropertyNames.IndexOf(k.Name)).ToList();
}
```